# get() returned more than one Product -- it returned 2 Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, web

DRF returning this: get() returned more than one Product -- it returned 2!, when im trying to get objects from my DB by PK

**Serializers**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # cat_id = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='cat_id', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'cat_id', 'use', 'diametr', 'len', 'color', 'photo')
```

**Views**

```
class CategoryProductView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        product = Product.objects.get(cat_id=pk)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Urls**
`path('api/categorylist/<int:pk>', CategoryProductView.as_view())`

Comment: Can you show your `model` and `response (JSON)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to serialize all items belonging to a certain primary key of a category, you filter, and serialize `many=True` items, so:

```
class CategoryProductView(APIView):
    
    def get(self, request, pk):
        products = Product.objects.filter(cat_id=pk)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: u just rescued me,appreciate it